# vuejs use babel plugin-proposal-class-properties

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

I have a class where I use some static properties like this:

```js
class Entity {
  static LIMIT = 10;
}
```

So, i can do:

```js
Entity.LIMIT
```

In order to do that I'm using babel `plugin-proposal-class-properties` and in my `.babelrc` I have:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

I'm using jest and my test passes using that config. Now I need to use funcionality of `Entity` class inside a `vuejs` component. But I got the error:
**Module parse failed: Unexpected token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type**

I also tried a babel config file in my project root: `babel.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
  plugins: [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
};
```

But didn't work.
**How can i configure vuejs, to make work this babel plugin?**

I'm using **vue2.6.11** and **vue-cli 3**

Comment: This should be doable out of the box with Vue-CLI 3. Did you try doing it without this particular babel plugin?

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: Nop, I just stop research

Answer (score 1):

I got this exact same issue when trying to use "importabular" with vuejs (vuejs 2, vue-cli-3). Importabular uses class properties, after some research I found this babel plugins (`plugin-proposal-class-properties`), I installed it and added it in vue.config.js.

To finally make it work, I had to add "importabular" (or the nested path) in the `transpileDependencies:` option. Why that? Because, by default, Babel ignores whatever is in node_module, so you have to tell Babel to not ignore this specific folder.

So, if you want to use babel or some babel plugins with some node_module with vue you should modify the vue.config.js as follow :

```js
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'path/in/node_module',
  ],
}
```

and change the babel.config.js as follow:

```js
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
  ]
}
```

Comment: Creator of importabular here, had no idea about this detail, will be solved in the next version by applying the transform to the build file